# Swagger generated API for the Microsoft Cognative Services Recommendations

Tags: azure

I can't seem to figure out how to include the CSV file content when calling the Swagger API generated methods for the Microsoft Cognitive Services Recommendations API method Uploadacatalogfiletoamodel(modelID, catalogDisplayName, accountKey);. I've tried setting the catalogDisplayName to the full path to the catalog file, however I'm getting "(EXT-0108) Passed argument is invalid."

When calling any of the Cog Svcs APIs that require HTTP body content, how do I include the body content when the exposed API doesn't have a parameter for the body?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Swagger can't help you testing functions that need to pass data thru a form. And I guess sending the CSV content in the form data shall do the trick, if you know the proper headers.

I work with nuGet called "Microsoft.Net.Http" and code looks like

```
HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(someStringYouWannaSend);
HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(someBytesYouWannaSend);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(stringContent, "metadata", "metadata");
    formData.Add(bytesContent, "bytes", "bytes");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(someWebApiEndPoint.ToString(), formData).Result;
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return false; //LOG
    }
    string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    jsonResult= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someCoolClass>(responseContent);
    return true;
}
```

Sorry about that someVariables that can't compile. Hope you'll figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are basing your code on the Swagger definition you depend on the good will of the person that created that Swagger definition. Maybe it is not complete yet.

If you are working on C#, try looking at the [Samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Recommendations-Windows).

Particularly for the Uploading of the catalog there are several functions on the ApiWrapper class that might be helpful, [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Recommendations-Windows/blob/master/Sample/RecommendationsApiWrapper.cs#L69) has this signature: `public CatalogImportStats UploadCatalog(string modelId, string catalogFilePath, string catalogDisplayName)`, [another](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Recommendations-Windows/blob/master/Sample/RecommendationsApiWrapper.cs#L99) has this other signature `public UsageImportStats UploadUsage(string modelId, string usageFilePath, string usageDisplayName)` (where it seems like you can point to a public url).

In your case I'd probably try the second one.

Download the sample and use the Wrapper code defined there in your project.